# 3D Touch Peek with Top Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, 3dtouch, peek-pop

I have a **UICollectionView** that shows 'Peek' when **3D Touch**'ed.  As default behavior, 'Peek' ignores navigation bars.

However, I do want to show a bar just as in **iMessage Peek** shown below:

[image]

Both Collection View Controller & Peek View Controller are inside Navigation View Controller.

I have following snippet from Apple's Sample code below that I am trying to modify in to above needs:

```
extension ChatTableViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ChatDetailViewController.identifier)
        guard let chatDetailViewController = viewController as? ChatDetailViewController else { return nil }

        chatDetailViewController.chatItem = chatItem(at: indexPath)
        let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        previewingContext.sourceRect = previewingContext.sourceView.convert(cellRect, from: tableView)
        chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = true

        return chatDetailViewController
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        if let chatDetailViewController = viewControllerToCommit as? ChatDetailViewController {
            chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = false
        }
        show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }
```

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to **Leo Natan** I was able to accomplish above:

```
extension ChatTableViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ChatDetailViewController.identifier)
        guard let chatDetailViewController = viewController as? ChatDetailViewController else { return nil }

        chatDetailViewController.chatItem = chatItem(at: indexPath)
        let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        previewingContext.sourceRect = previewingContext.sourceView.convert(cellRect, from: tableView)
        chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = true

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController
        return navigationController
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        if let chatDetailViewController = viewControllerToCommit as? ChatDetailViewController {
            chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = false
        }
        show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }
```

However, this creates a NEW Navigation Controller.  If I want to end up with the same same Navigation Controller, I can do this:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    if let chatDetailViewController = viewControllerToCommit as? ChatDetailViewController {
        chatDetailViewController.isReplyButtonHidden = false
    }

    show((viewControllerToCommit as UIController).viewControllers[0], sender: self)
}
```

**show((viewControllerToCommit as UIController).viewControllers[0], sender: self)** extracts the viewController out of it's Navigation Controller.  Does this have any downsides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `previewingContext(_:, viewControllerForLocation:)`, wrap your view controller in a `UINavigationController` and return that.

Comment: self.navigationController!.pushViewController(chatDetailViewController, animated: false) I tried that, causing a crash.

Comment: Why are you pushing? Return a *new* navigation controller, wrapping `chatDetailViewController`.

Comment: Perfect. let navigationController = 'UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)'
         and then 'return navigationController'.  That worked!

Comment: I marked the your reply as correct because you answered what I originally asked for.  However, by wrapping viewController around a NEW UINavigationController, when the viewController is committed, it's a new navigration controller.  It's missing back button and other elements.  To fix this, is there a way to return the same UINavigationController the view controller is currently in?

Comment: No. You need to throw the wrapper navigation controller and commit the char detail controller directly.